# Highcharts change value out of csv file before plotting as epoch time not in ms so it has to be multiplied by 1000

Tags: csv, highcharts

I found the posibillity to use a callback function after reading the csv file in the highcharts . But my knowledge ist not good enough to get the first value per line and multiply by 1000. I am starting from the code out of an example found: (https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/parsed/)

```
data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
        parsed: function (columns) {
            // We want to keep the values since 1950 only
            $.each(columns, function () {
                // Keep the first item which is the series name, then remove the following 70
                this.splice(1, 70);
            });
        }
    },
```

I have to put my code instead of the "this.splice(1,70)" but no idea how.

My data look like:

```
Date,Temp,Press
1552417882, 25.54,980.23
1552417942, 25.60,980.19
1552418002, 25.60,980.17
1552418062, 25.58,980.14
1552418122, 25.53,980.12
1552418183, 25.48,980.06
1552418243, 25.48,980.06
1552418303, 25.47,980.04
1552418363, 25.47,980.02
```

And also the first line (description) should be unchanged.

Best regards
Albert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the structure of the columns array and loop through the first inner array to recalculate the timestamp:

```
data: {
    csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
    parsed: function(columns) {
        columns[0].forEach(function(column, i) {
            columns[0][i] *= 1000;
        });
    }
},
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zve9tsa8/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.parsed

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand the code now, but unfortunately I am not using the innerHTML. I am getting the values from my Arduino by requesting the csv file, If using your code the chart is not displayed.

Comment: Hi @albert8413, You can edit your question because asking another question as an answer is not a good idea. Please provide me with the `csv` variable output.

Comment: I did some copying error. Its working! So thanks really a lot. I wanted to be quick as its morning in Austria and I have to drive to my work. So really thanks a lot.